# Failed get back video after extract content and base64 encode it using PHP

Tags: php, html, video, base64, mp4

I have tried to get back my video (mp4) after I get contents then I base64 encode it, but my video is still not playing. I have tried the code below with images and it works. Why doesn't it work with videos?

```
<?php
    $con=file_get_contents("kecak.mp4"); //kecak.mp4 work to play with <video> </video> tag
    $en=base64_encode($con);
    $binary_data='data:'.$mime.';base64,'. $en ;
?>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="<?php echo $binary_data ?>" type="video/mp4" /> 
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: what is value of $mime variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a length restriction for base64_encode. When the input is too long it doesn't output anything. I don't have your video or the details of it to test it, but I think chunk_split could help you out here: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php.

Comment: thx u. but not take effect. i try to edit like below, its work. but i don't know why i should add AAAS
 $en=base64_encode(trim($con));
 $binary_data='data:'.$mime.';base64,AAAA'. $en ;

Comment: this is the video [link](http://www.rey1024.com/wp-content/uploads/kecak.mp4) i have similiar question but different :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829710/video-tag-html5-with-src-from-base64-encode-not-work-on-different-device-and-bro

Answer (score 0):

```
   // works for me
    $img_str = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)); // encode file
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // allow all CORS // dev only
    header("Content-Type: text/plain"); // resp file header
    echo($img_str);  // echo base64 string
```