# video tag html5 with src from base64_encode not work on different device and browser

Tags: html, video, browser, base64, restful-architecture

i try this code.

```
<video width="320" height="240"  controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer">
<source src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA<?php echo   chunk_split(base64_encode(trim(file_get_contents('kecak.mp4'))));  ?>" type="video/mp4" /> 
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

it's work when i play in Notebook(safari, firefox) but not work when i play on IPAD2(safari) or Samsung Galaxy(Opera).
 i think the problem is in

```
src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA<?php echo chunk_split(base64_encode(trim(file_get_contents('kecak.mp4'))));  ?>
```

because when i replace with

```
src="kecak.mp4"
```

it's work at all device and browser. i must use **base64_encode(trim(file_get_contents('kecak.mp4')))** because in real my case it's come from response from RESTFul to delivery video via http. string response from http same with base64_encode(trim(file_get_contents('kecak.mp4'))).
thx u for help :-)

Comment: this is the video ([link]http://www.rey1024.com/wp-content/uploads/kecak.mp4)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you add AAAA?
may be try just like this:
< ?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($yourfile));?>

B